# How to open an application from a toast notification other than the one which created it in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, toast

I have created a Windows Phone 8.1 application, which can send toast notification to the action center of windows phone. Now  I need to open another application when the user clicks on the toast notification. How can I implement this..? 
I am able to open the same application, which created the toast notification.
How can I open another app, which I specify...?

Comment: There is no way to do this; you can only open your own application. What application are you trying to launch? There are possibilities to launch your own app and then immediately launch another app.

Comment: Just consider a situation in which I have given a background service to download something. When the download is complete it will create a toast notification. Now when i click that notification, I want to launch an app.

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter Torr pointed out, launching other applications than your on is just not possible (and will probably not become available).

You can launch some system apps and other apps that registered a known protocol using [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) and fire it right on the start of your app when the user tapped the toast notification.

Comment: Or LaunchFileAsync since this is about downloaded files.

Comment: @Kai.....I tried using **Launcher.LaunchUriAsync** to launch my app, but for a small instance of time the other app which calles **Launcher.LaunchUriAsync** is displayed in the screen, I dont want that to happen....Is there a way to do this...? Can we do it by making the calling app a background service..?

Comment: No chance. You will always get at least a glimpse of the SplashScreen. I don't think LaunchUriAsync is available from a background app, because launching/closing an app should always be the result of a user interaction.

Comment: @KaiBrummund , is this still true until now?

Comment: You can add <toast activationType='protocol' launch='bingmaps:?q=1+Microsoft+Way,+98052'> to open Bing maps or add URL to open websites. You can also define your own protocols apparently but the documentation is outdated and for windows 8